# How to initialize typescript data-structure quickly inline

Tags: typescript, interface

I was looking for a shortcut to crate a quick data-structure that I can access the data by key.
I thought I can use a custom dictionary for that.

So I have this interface:

```
interface Dictionary<T> {
  [Key: string]: T;
}
```

I want to initialize it is like that:

```
data: Dictionary<string> = {
    ['key']: { a: 1, b: 2 }
  }
```

But I've got an error `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'`

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, since it's not valid syntax, bit neither 1, nor 2, not {a: 1, b: 2} are strings. A Dictionary<string> would look like `{foo: 'hello', bar: 'world' }`: an object with keys associated to string values.

Comment: OK. But do you understand that a string, a number, and an object are not the same thing? In a dictionary of strings, you can't store numbers or objects. Because they are not strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{ a: 1, b: 2}` isn't a `string`, but you're trying to use it as the value of a property in an object with the index signature `[Key: string]: string` (because `T` is `string`).

If you want the value to be an object with properties `a` and `b`, you need to use an appropriate type for that, not `string`. For instance:

```
interface Dictionary<T> {
  [Key: string]: T;
}

const data: Dictionary<{ a: number, b: number }> = {
    key: { a: 1, b: 2}
};
```

Or better yet, define a type for it, and use the type:

```
interface Dictionary<T> {
  [Key: string]: T;
}

type Example = { a: number, b: number };
const data: Dictionary<Example> = {
    key: { a: 1, b: 2}
};
```

[Live example on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCLAWYB7EcoCeAPACoB8yA3gFDLIDaA0hAQFzIDOYUoA5gLrsSAbmoBfatTAEADigCiADzgBbGQBsUAXirI47EAFcVAI2gAaZCYPGzUZGNEJcXZABM4YfWgxZc+YiVVDQgKHRo6OgBrFnZKPXYARktrZAAmCUcgA)

---

Side note 1: There's no need to use computed property syntax with a string literal (`['key']`). Just use a string literal or a property name literal.

Side note 2:

> I was looking for a shortcut to crate a quick data-structure that I can access the data by key.

[`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is good for that. Or if you know the values of the keys in advance, a defined object type or [`Record<K, T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt).

Comment: Record utility thing works well for me. Thanks for pointing that out!